# Children's book with a house made of cardboard boxes that has the power to travel back in time to King Arthur's time

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm looking for a children's book I read, probably around 2008. The main character is a boy, who builds a house in his backyard out of cardboard boxes, a couple of storeys tall I think. At least one of the cardboard boxes has the ability to travel to some time/place where King Arthur is alive. When the time travel happens, the box glows blue.

Can anyone help identify this book?

Comment: It's not the "Magic Treehouse" series is it?

Comment: I took a look and it does seem superficially similar, but no I don't think it's the one I'm thinking of. Thanks though! :)